# Flutter Webview get values from javascript

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webview

how to get an javascript function and callback from flutter webview

i was following the documentation and still can't getting the values

here the code :

```
  void _initWebController() async {
    if (widget.toTransferWebViewArguments.urlTransferLead?.isNotEmpty == true) {
      urlSitePlan = widget.toTransferWebViewArguments.urlTransferLead ?? "";
    } else {
      urlSitePlan =
          widget.toTransferWebViewArguments.urlTransferLeadToOtherSales ?? "";
    }

    print("url ${widget.toTransferWebViewArguments.urlTransferLead}");
    print(
        "url ${widget.toTransferWebViewArguments.urlTransferLeadToOtherSales}");

    controller = WebViewController()
      ..runJavaScript('javascript:doSelectUser(message)')
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..addJavaScriptChannel('selectUnit',
          onMessageReceived: _onMessageReceived)
      ..addJavaScriptChannel('selectPersonal',
          onMessageReceived: _onMessageReceived)
      ..addJavaScriptChannel('doSelectUser',
          onMessageReceived: _onMessageReceived)
      ..addJavaScriptChannel('Android', onMessageReceived: _onMessageReceived)
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(urlSitePlan));
  }

  void _onMessageReceived(JavaScriptMessage message) {
    if (message != null) {
      var decodedMsg = JSON.jsonDecode(message.message);
      String lightningLink = decodedMsg["doSelectUser"];

      Navigator.pop(context, lightningLink.substring(10));
    }
  }
}
```